# Show $(1 + O(x))^2 = O(1)$ near any $a \in \mathbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The functions $f$ inside $1 + O(x)$ are of the form $1 + f(x)$ with $|f(x)| \le C|x|$ for some $C>0$. Then $(1 + O(x))^2$ is a set of functions of the form $1 + 2f(x) + f(x)^2$ where $|2f(x)| \le 2C|x|, \ |(f(x))^2| \le (C|x|)^2 = C^2|x|^2$. If we show $1 + 2C|x| + C^2|x^2| \le D$ for some $D> 0$, we are done. If $x \in (a, a + \varepsilon)$, then $|x| \le \sup(a, a + \varepsilon)$ and so we have $2C|x| \le \max\{2C\sup(a - \varepsilon, a), 2C\sup(a, a + \varepsilon)\} = E$. Then $|x| \le \frac{E}{2C}$ and so $1 + 2C|x| + C^2|x^2| \le 1 +E + \frac{E^2}{4}.$ Does this proof work?